# jquery button not appending

Tags: jquery, html

If anyone can help. New to jquery. When I insert data the first and second td appends but the 3rd td does not which contains the button for deleting. What am I doing wrong in this code? If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function){
      $('#addToTable').click(function() {
        var equipment = $('#equipment').val(),
            quantity = $('#qnty-1').val();
        $('#crud_table').append('<tr><td>' + equipment + '</td><td>' + quantity + '</td><td><button name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">-</button></td></tr>');
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: @Taplar My bad. Changed it already but still wont show up or wont append the 3rd td :(

Comment: Change `}
  </script>` to `});
  </script>`

Comment: Any errors in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)? (lol)

Comment: Also typo with `$(document).ready(function){`, good lord, lol.

Comment: Additional advice, unless your job requires it, I would never use HTML tables (except email, but you can't use javascript, and MAYBE some display circumstances). Also, since you're obtaining your values from an input every time, creating self-containing variables outside the click event for `#equipment` and `#quantity`, then inside the click event, accessing the values, is good practice. Don't forget to use `$.trim` as well

Comment: @RobScott Still a student so trying to learn all this. Thanks for the knowledge. will surely take note of that!

Comment: @Anthony.Jay no worries! Don't forget to check `console` (Chrome dev tools) and/or using an online JS validator (ie - https://codebeautify.org/jsvalidate). I briefly looked over this site, but this would be good to go over. http://jqfundamentals.com/. After you get that down, learn React, nodeJS, or Angular. You'll be amazed

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have typos.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#addToTable').click(function() {
        var equipment = $('#equipment').val(),
            quantity = $('#qnty-1').val();
        $('#crud_table').append('<tr><td>' + equipment + '</td><td>' + quantity + '</td><td><button name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">-</button></td></tr>');
      });
    });
</script>
```